# How to implement "Share with apps" functionality in iOS 17?

Tags: ios, swift, ios17, share-extension

I am trying to create an app extension that i can use in a shortcut using the "share with apps" action. I have the extension created AND it shows up in the regular share sheet for just sharing anything. However, when i go into the shortcut app to create an automation that use the "Share with apps" action and try to select my app, i only see health, linkedin, slack, reminders, and a few other apps. What is different about this share functionality vs regular share functionality?

Does anyone know how to make their app show up in the list of apps you can select when you are in shortcuts using "Share with apps" action?

To be more specific. here is example. [image: Image of pinterest showing]One image attached shows the shortcut of taking screenshot and opening pinterest which still in the original app (in this example it was the Notes app).

The other screenshot shows my shortcut setup.[image: Image of shortcuts] The goal here is for me to select my app instead of pinterest. I dont see my app listed in the list of apps to select. I have tried app intents, intents, share extensions but clearly doing something wrong. Thanks!

**Update**

OK so i have my ActionExtension working BUT only in simulator. When i go to try on my device i do not see it. Attached shows simulator. [image: Simulator]

Also, when i try to run the shortcut i get this error [image: error]
Does anyone know why this would be the case? My updated rule is `SUBQUERY ( extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY ( $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ( ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" ) ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count ).@count == 1`

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the corresponding UTI types in your `info.plist`?

For example, if your extension supports:

- text > `public.text`
- or, images > `public.image`

### info.plist

```xml
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Public Text</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Public Image</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: I did try this but no luck

Answer (score 1):

A share extension is indeed the way to go to achieve that. Based on your screenshots, it appears that you already implemented the extension.

I re-created the same shortcut as yours in an iOS simulator and actuall managed to get a share extension working using the same `NSActivationRule` you used in your question. That being said, there is a simpler way to do the same with the following configuration:

In the `Info.plist` of your share extension target, you should have something like this:

```xml
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

- `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` defines the type of extension, here a share extension,
- `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` points to the storyboard containing your share extension UI,
- `NSExtensionActivationRule` defines when the share sheet should show your extension based on the UTI type of the data being shared.

Here the activation rule is set to `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` with a count of one. This means that the extension only shows up when a single image is being shared, which is what the shortcut is doing. Please note that this is simply a shorthand doing the same thing as the activation rule from your question.

#### Testing on simulator

Another thing to take into account is that Xcode sometimes have issues deploying the latest version of an extension on a simulator or device. The most reliable way to test I found to test this is to run the extension target and then select the Shortcut app as the host application.

[image: Menu to select host application for the extension]

#### Testing on a device

Finally, on a device, it looks like the "Share with apps" step only list applications signed with a distribution certificate. Using a TestFlight build is probably the way to go to test it on your device once it works in your simulator.

Comment: here is the flow that i want. I want to create a shortcut that takes a screenshot when i tap the phone. Which i have working. From there i want that media saved and then i want it passed into my App extension so i can take the image and process it. I want to stay in the original app i was in when i took the screenshot and show a UI on top with the results of my processed image. Right now as example i can do this and get slack to come up overlayed on top where i can then interact as if i were to post that image. Instead i want me app to show up for me to look at the image.

Comment: I tried the intents framework with UI but its not showing in the shortcuts app action "share with apps" to be able to select my app. If i use AppIntents can i have a interactive UI? @Sparga

Comment: I see you edited your post with more details and now I understand better what you are trying to do. 
The AppIntent framework is meant to implement a single step that can be then used in a shortcut. To use the existing "Share with apps" step, your initial idea of making a share extension was correct. As for why your app doesn't appears in the list it could be because the NSExtensionActivationRule in the extension's Info.plist is incorrect. Can you share this part in your original post as well?

Comment: Updated the original post with my latest update. any help is appreciated @sparga